# D&D 3.5 Campaign for low level characters that can be run in 30 - 45 minute sessions

Tags: dnd-3.5e, game-recommendation, campaign

I am specifically looking for campaigns that are balanced for low level characters in D&D 3.5.

I would accept any campaigns though free is preferred.

The campaign itself does not need to end in the single session just have 'checkpoints' that would allow the short sessions.

Comment: Aaron, can you give us some idea of what kind of players you have, and what kind of characters they want to play?

Comment: As this is a [tag:game-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and the guidance on recommendation questions on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Comment: The exact amount of time for a session would vary by group, but 30-45 minutes seems outrageously short. I've never seen a group that could do anything significant in such a short period.

Comment: Combats are going to be a huge barrier; they'd need to be utterly trivial to run or able to pick up and carry on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a *campaign*, but I'm a fan of *Gorgoldand's Gauntlet* as a low-level *adventure*.  It was a published *Dungeon* adventure from May 2001 (this obviously makes it 3.0 and not 3.5, but I don't expect it would be difficult to update).  A quick search turned up this PDF version:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120127074715/http://gilda.it/imperium/download/gauntlet.pdf

My experience with it is that it takes more than 30-45 minutes to play through.  However, there are different rooms and encounters that could be used as a breaking point.  I've used this specific adventure to introduce people to role-playing in the past with great success.

Answer (score -2):

I have been a DM almost my entire gaming life and I have found that the home made games, not the "campaigns" have the most flexibility on time and pausing or stopping points.  As the DM you will put more time in to the game then your players but the outcome will be what you are working for and that is your time restraint.

For example, set the stage of a low-level location as a village or "home base" for your low levelers. Instead of questing and campaigning, work on village improvements for long term changes to the game. The blacksmith needs a bigger forge for better gear. Quest in your timeframe to go to a goblin den and "sneak" or "raid" their goblin Blacksmith for his larger warforge. Now your adventurers can get masterwork gear when they have their next adventure! Net and gather Wild horses, gather rare metals… anything to improve the home base.

Comment: We are not a forum. Personal exchanges of messages don't exist. Instead of listing that you want to help, perhaps distill your wisdom into this answer?

Comment: There is an "edit" button for making improvements to answers. Use that instead of comments when expanding on an answer. I've gone ahead and edited your comment into the answer this time.

Comment: Also, while your answer is a valid point, it is customary here to assume that the asker has reasons to ask his question the way he did. Meaning, if he wants a published campaign, thats what the answers should focus on, instead of telling him to write his own.

Answer (score -2):

It is hard to run a game in 45 minute sections.  You will have to adjust combat mechanics, or one combat session could be your whole game.  That being said, any of the published campaigns have suitable challenges and enemies for low level characters.  Taking on the Dark Sun slavers, fighting a goblin war in the Forgotten Realms, and searching for a treasure lost in the desert of Al Qadim are all great ways to start a low level campaign.

Comment: This seems to be suggesting a home-made campaign in a published campaign *setting*, while the question is asking for a published *campaign*.

Comment: YMMV, in the groups I've played with, sessions with a combat usually have that combat be most or all of the session, even with sessions being typically 3-5 hours.